# Как правильно выстроить обработку исключений и насколько соблюдается SOLID? Оцените код C#

Tags: c#, .net, инспекция-кода

Проект совсем небольшой, хотел бы получить критику по поводу кода, это моё решённое тестовое задание. Его уже проверили, поэтому делаю рефакторинг и работаю над ошибками уже для себя. Была проведена работа по соответствию принципам SOLID, поэтому буду рад критике по этому поводу - чего упустил, чего сделал неправильно.
Обработка исключений пожалуй самая большая проблема, множественные try catch замедляют программу, поэтому я оставил всего один. Если не затруднит дайте пожалуйста рекомендации по поводу работы с исключениями в программе или посоветовали какой-нибудь материал. И в конце концов прошу оценить код в целом, возможно с точки зрения производительности или потенциальных проблем.
Вот ссылка на весь код: https://github.com/deflarten/SaveAndPrintProject

Comment: Тестовое задание без юнит тестов?

Comment: Инспекция кода подразумевает "не весь проект", а какой-то конкретной части, которую нужно запостить в вопрос. Вы если хотите весь проект оценить -- лучше бы в [шарповый чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--) шли.

Comment: 1) Исключение - это медленно. 2) Строить логику на исключениях неэффективно. ... ну и что что юзер не дал вам аргументов, это ожидаемый сценарий? Да. Написать код так, чтобы эта ситуация входила в логику приложения можно? Да. Трассировка стека вызовов вам нужна? Нет. Выход из метода по стеку вызовов в ближайший `catch` нужен? Нет. Тогда зачем здесь исключение? `if (args.Length == 0) { DisplayError("Не передано ни одного аргумента."); DisplayHelp(); return; }` По этому же принципу рассуждений посмотрите на все свои остальные `throw`.

Comment: Да, кстати, перед ссылкой на весь проект, вставьте код из `Program.cs` в сам вопрос, там хватает проблем для обсуждения. В противном случае получается вопрос-ссылка, а это не формат для StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Чтож, пойдем с начала

1. Нет юнит тестов
2. Проект вперемешку с солюшеном
3. Что за папка "Interfaces"? А где папки "CLasses" и "Enums"?
4. Каша с названиями

Какие то несуразные названия

> ICsvConstructor

зачем для этого нужен интерфейс? Интерфейс нужен, если планируется иметь несколько реализаций. Например, если вы планируете и в CVS и в Word - тогда можно интерфейс.

И почему "Constructor"? Откуда это слово вообще? Для экспорта данных есть слово - Export.

> IDbProvider

Provide - это "предоставлять", то есть TimeProvider - предоставляем время. DbProvider - предоставляет БД. В методах интерфейса нет ничего про БД

> IWebProvider
> public string GetDownloadedFilename(string url);

Во-первых, это не предоставляет Web.
Во-вторых - название `GetDownloadedFilename` предполагает, что файл уже скачан и надо только его имя вернуть.

> IYmlParser
> public IEnumerable GetItems(string filename, string shopId);

Почему бы парсеру не иметь метод `Parse`? Что такое `shopId`? Что за Items?

> class Item

Почему бы просто не назвать `class MyClass`? Названия классов и интерфейсов должны выражать их назначение, а не быть случайным набором букв.

> PrintExecutor

Почему для других классов есть интерфейс, а для этого - нет? Также Print и Execute - это 2 действия, так? Класс походу не делает ни того, ни другого.

5. С одной стороны у вас какое то подобие IoC

> private static ServiceProvider ConfigureServices() {...}

С другой стороны

> var printExecutor = new PrintExecutor(dbProvider, csvConstructor);

Дальше читать не стал.

По итогу:

Видно, что вы начинающий, который старался как мог.

Хорошо: пытаетесь прийти к какой то архитектуре

Плохо:

- проблемы с именованием типов и неймспейсов
- непонятные методы типа `GetString(int foo, int bar)` - название и сигнатура метода должны говорить о том, что он делает
- Проблемы с пониманием, когда надо интерфейсы и когда не надо и зачем вообще интерфейсы нужны
- Не следуете своей же архитектуре - вроде IoC, а вроде и не IoC
- Пробелы в самой архитектуре. У вас в задании сказано, что вы обрабатываете команды, но нет класса "Команда" у вас. С одной стороны используете интерфейсы для (наверное) гибкости и расширяемости, с другой стороны обработка команд у вас простой swith-case